# Deploying Multiple Immutant WAR files to Wildfly

Tags: clojure, wildfly, immutant

I don't think this is version specific but I'll specify I'm on `Immutant 2.1.0` and `Wildfly 9.0.1.Final`.

I start with a stock, freshly unzipped wildfly download and run it with `$ wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh`. I run `$ lein immutant war` in my clojure project with the following in my `project.clj`:

```
:immutant {:war {:destination "/srv/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/"
                 :context-path "/app1}}
```

This works fine and I have my app at `http://localhost:8080/app1`. The problem is when I do this with a second app with `:context-path "/app2"`, wildfly complains:

```
>Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: 
 Service jboss.pojo.\"org.jboss.netty.internal.LoggerConfigurator\".DESCRIBED 
 is already registered"
```

If I do this process with app2 before app1, app2 gets correctly deployed but app1 gets a complaint. Both can be deployed individually but not at the same time.

I don't know if I'm missing a step at `WAR` time or missing wildfly configuration or what.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Immutant trying to install a server with the same name twice.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins See my answer below. Is it a correct assessment? Is there a better way to work around the issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the netty jar having a `jboss-beans.xml` file, which is detected by the "pojo" subsystem in WildFly, and used to set up a LoggerConfigurator bean. Each app must have a dependency on netty (probably transitively), which causes WildFly to attempt to deploy the same bean twice. One workaround is to disable the pojo subsystem in WildFly by editing the appropriate `standalone/configuration/standalone*.xml` file and commenting out the pojo subsystem (you may need to comment out both `<extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>` and `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>`).

Comment: I assume immutant can use the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as well right? If so it can be used to exclude the `pojo` subsystem as well. Though removing it if it's not being used is fine too.

Comment: Yes, we include a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the war to set up the module dependencies for the app, and allow the user to provide a customized one, so that would be another option. I had forgotten that subsystems could be disabled from there.

Comment: Otherwise remove dependency to netty.jar and reinclude it via jboss-deployment-structure.xml and reference to module org.jboss.netty.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when I was trying to deploy two applications on jboss with hornetq-jms-server. The root cause was an extra jboss-beans.xml in the netty jar. I am not sure in which version exactly was it removed, but switching to hornet 2.4.7.Final, that uses netty-all 4.0.13.Final did the job. 
Here is information about the defect https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1996